# "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast" error in ModalRoute.of(context).settings

Tags: flutter, dart, null

I'm trying to pass an argument through Navigator like this:

```
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(EditProductScreen.routeName, arguments: id);
```

But when trying to retrieve it using `final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String;`
I'm getting this error: **type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast**.
I've also tried using the bang `!` operator but with no luck.

Comment: Can you show how you used `!` operator? Because this is working for me. `ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String`

Comment: I've used it exactly like that but I'm getting the same error

Comment: What flutter version are you using. If not the latest one, then try upgrading it.

Comment: I'm on stable 2.2.1, the latest one

Comment: where are you calling ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments?

Comment: In a didChangeDependencies() function outside the build method

Answer (score 11):

I also have the same problem and this is my code and works as a charm.

```
final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String?;
  if (productId != null) {
    _editedProduct =
        Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).findById(productId);
    _initValues = {
      'title': _editedProduct.title,
      'description': _editedProduct.description,
      'price': _editedProduct.price.toString(),
```

Answer (score 4):

```
final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String
```

If you are getting error, Add ? after string

```
final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String?
```

If you are still getting error go to the file where you declared productId and change it from `String productId` to `String? productId` and add `'!'` to the productid in the place where you are getting error

Answer (score 1):

I somewhat managed to make it at least compile changing

`final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String;`

to

`final String? productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments.toString() ?? "";`

It still throws me an error:

`Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.`

but it seems to be working for now.
If you have any suggestions to make it work without complaints go ahead though!

Answer (score -1):

`final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String`

just add ? to end of this line like that:
`final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String?`
It works!

Comment: Still getting an error, `Null check operator used on a null value`

Comment: Using ! on a null value will throw this exception. Instead use ? like this ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String?